# Java generic exceptions for callable

Tags: java

Is there any way to get a class that explicitly throws the (non-runtime) exceptions and only the (non-runtime) exceptions that the body throws?

I know how to do this with a fixed number of exceptions, like:

```
public interface Throw1Callable<T, E extends Exception> {
    public T call() throws E;
}
```

This way, when call is invoked, you don't have to handle Exception and instead only have to handle RuntimeExceptions and E. But this doesn't scale at all. If I wanted to do this for two exception, I'd need to make a new class for Throw2Callable etc. And Java (and probably all languages) doesn't offer variable number of generics or anything of the sort that might help.

Is there a good way of encapsulating the above?

edit for clarification: Let's say A.a throws IOException. I'd like to be able to do `((Throw1Callable)() -> A.a()).call()`  and catch only IOException instead of catching Exception. `((Callable)() -> A.a()).call()` will throw Exception instead of just IOException.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `get a class that explicitly throws the (non-runtime) exceptions`. Do you want to create a method that can throw any Exception?

Comment: I added some things for clarity. I mean that if the body throws some exception, like IOException, .call should throw only IOException instead of Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to some kind of "vararg" type parameter which is not possible in Java.

So probably `ThrowXCallable` is the best you can do here. I don't think "scalability" is a big problem here, you will probably not need more than `Throw5Callable`.

Java itself takes this approach - see `BiFunction`.

Comment: I was hoping that there's a better solution that this, but you're probably right. I probably will never need more than Throw3.